# PHP Make GET understand 0

Tags: php, get

How can I make "GET" understand the number 0 without it understanding that 0 is nothing?

```
if(empty($_GET['number'])) {
echo "No GET variables"; 
}

if($_GET['number']){
$number=strip_tags(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['number'])));
echo $number;
}
```

If the variable "number" = 1 it will echo "1" but if the number is 0 it will echo "No GET variables"

How can I make it understand 0 as well as other numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`empty` returns `true` if you give it a `0`; you can use `isset` instead to check whether it is set (regardless of value):

```
if(isset($_GET['number']))
```

from http://php.net/empty:

> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> - `""` (an empty string)
> - `0` (0 as an integer)
> - `0.0` (0 as a float)
> - `"0"` (0 as a string)
> - `NULL`
> - `FALSE`
> - `array()` (an empty array)
> - `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

My test:

```
$_GET['number'] = "0";
assert(isset($_GET['number']));

$_GET['number'] = 0;
assert(isset($_GET['number']));
```

Your code should look like:

```
if(!isset($_GET['number'])) {
   echo "No GET variables"; 
}

if(isset($_GET['number'])) {
   $number=strip_tags(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['number'])));
   echo $number;
}
```

Or more concise

```
if(!isset($_GET['number'])) {
   echo "No GET variables"; 
} else {
   $number=strip_tags(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['number'])));
   echo $number;
}
```

Comment: If I do that will it echo "0"?

Comment: @SamHam I've just tested and yes, indeed.. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @SamHam Does it still echo `"No GET variables"` ?

Comment: @SamHam Are you sure `$_GET['number']` indeed contains "0"? Try `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: @SamHam: What's the value of `$_GET['steal']`?

Comment: The number are from 0 to 5 so yes

Comment: @SamHam edited my answer with some tests I'm running and it passed all the `assert`'s... what's the output of `var_dump($_GET)`? Could you post it?

Comment: @SamHam edited my answer with the complete code, see if we are on the same page

Comment: @SamHam I thought you asked me to add your fB? :O

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9923/discussion-between-sam-ham-and-niftydude)

Answer (score 1):

try this: using the 3rd char of the operator

```
if ($_GET['number'] !== '')
```

Comment: that's not a "3rd char". it's the strict comparison operator.